# User not able to reset password

Tags: salesforce2salesforce

I got a user ,with email id abc@company.com

This person has two different users registered under this same abc@company.com

For one user ,there is federation id (for that reason i presume SSO enabled)

for this second user.,,federation id is not enabled.

Issue is second users' password was reset and a temporary one was generated
When second user tries to reset a permanent password,its either logging him out..or saying account locked.

What could be the reason/solution?

Comment: WOW, I didn't know you can have 2 users with the same email. That's super weird. Are you sure there is no typo in one of the emails?  (probably the one without the federation ID)

Comment: its user name that should be unique within salesforce.you can have any number of users under same email id.Well second user does get password notifcation email etc.so it is definitely not a case of typo

Comment: Is this a Self Service Portal User?

Comment: no it is not portal user

Comment: if it's SSO (federated), isn't there a 3rd party that handles the passwords and passwords resets? did you try there?

Comment: yeah..they are telling its a salesforce error.not sure why :)